# How do i change the background color of just the accessory view (ios)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview, uibackgroundcolor

I can change the cell background by just `cell.backgroundColor`
but i have tried `cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor` and `cell.editingAccessoryView.backgroundColor` without any success.
I am using the standard disclosure indicator `>`
I am pretty sure it could be done with a custom button.
But is there not any way i can do it using the default indicator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. i found a solution was to set the whole cell first (thus setting the accessory view too) and then set the content view which will be on top.

```
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:228.0/255.0 blue:157.0/255.0 alpha:0.25];
  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.25];
```